# Magento custom image attribute. How do I get in frontend?

Tags: php, magento

I've added an image attribute with name and label e.g. New Image, new_image.

How do I fetch this from e.g. view.phtml? I thought it would be as simple as

```
<?php
    echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'new_image')->resize(150, 150);
?>
```

But, this is throwing an error.

Does anybody know the correct way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please pick the most correct answer, I mean your question is also a bit wonky. A custom image attribute would be a image in another model not linked to product, as per my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schonkton, I can verify that your code worked just fine in catalog/product/view.phtml. I take it that you added the image attribute to the attribute group... A side note is that the output from the echo will deliver an image link, so needs to be enclosed in an image tag.

```
    echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'new_image')->resize(150, 150);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem displaying in list but finally found a way to solve it.
I found that the attribute is shown only in product view page not in list page.
So what I did was load the product once again as:

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

And when I used `$product` instead of `$_product` in the displaying image, i.e

```
helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'new_image')->resize(150, 150); ?>
```

it worked.

I know this is not a good way to do it but I don't know any other way. Maybe we could do something to select the attribute in list to.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is too late for you but it might help others. Following answer applies to product view page.

First check that either this attribute have some value or not.

```
$isNewImage =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('new_image')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

If it has some value selected from back end

```
<?php if ( $isNewImage != 'no_selection'):?>

$_newImg ='<img id="your-id" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'new_image')->resize(300,300).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';

 echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_newImg , 'new_image'); 

<?php  endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add custom placeholder image to your skin folder: `images/catalog/product/placeholder/custom_image.jpg`

Comment: Where "custom_image" is the name of your attribute. OP is using "new_image" therefore you would need an image called "new_image.jpg" in the skin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be that you are using $_product from a collection - try to load it first:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'new_image')->resize(150, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few valid string values for that init call: `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail`, corresponding to the product attributes for those images. If you want to call the images that way, you'll need to set the `new_image` to be one of those three images in the administration panel.

Otherwise, look for "gallery" methods on the product, as those will give you all your images to iterate through.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.

So, you can only call image, small_image and thumbnail that way?

I've added the attribute new_image as type media image.

What's the best way to fetch that image in view.phtml?

Also, how would I exclude images from the more views/gallery? Specifically, the new_image?

Many thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Farrukhs code is close to the best answer,

Although he assumes that we always have a $_helper object by default, if this is not the case just call echo where $_newImg attribute is cast

Secondly, I display my image in a jquery scriptoluscious popup window, and this code causes that window to open the site itself in the popup window, than on the 3rd level it displays my image attribute... It almost feels like the movie inception, when you keep clicking the popup within the popup frame until you get the image...Just wanted to share the bizzareness!

Answer (score 0):

> But, this is throwing an error.

I bet your error in *var/report* is like

```
Image not found
```

Make sure you uploaded the image to the product.
I suggest to use the example from bhab to prevent errors if products dont have the new image.

So, make sure

1. attribute *new_image* exist
2. attribute is in your current attribute set
3. *view.phtml* uses bhabs code
4. a new_image -image is given in product